# Pandas data manipulation: mapping a column with some predetermined values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data look like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

T1_Delivery = 20
T2_Delivery = 30
T3_Delivery = 40
T4_Delivery = 55

data = [
    {'Person': 'A', 'Present_Delivery': -10, 'update': 'T1'},
    {'Person': 'B', 'Present_Delivery': 30},
    {'Person': 'C', 'Present_Delivery': 40},
    {'Person': 'D', 'Present_Delivery': 70, 'update': 'T3'},
    {'Person': 'E', 'Present_Delivery': 50, 'update': 'T2'},
    {'Person': 'F', 'Present_Delivery': 50}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Actual_Delivery'] = np.where(df['update']==np.NaN, df['Present_Delivery'],0)

#map T{x} to T{x}_Delivery
```

I need to map update entry(x) with T{x}_Delivery as defined globally. Is this possible? I am able to map if _Delivery is not present in global definition.

My output is something like this:

```
data = [
    {'Person': 'A', 'Actual_Delivery': 20},
    {'Person': 'B', 'Actual_Delivery': 30},
    {'Person': 'C', 'Actual_Delivery': 40},
    {'Person': 'D', 'Actual_Delivery': 40},
    {'Person': 'E', 'Actual_Delivery': 30},
    {'Person': 'F', 'Actual_Delivery': 50}
]

df_desired = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

EDIT: This is part of a bigger script and it is not possible to change global variable to dictionary!

Comment: Instead of using a bunch of global variables for each `TX`, have you considered using a dictionary? This will make it more straight-forward to relate the values with their respective entries in the DataFrame.

Comment: Yes, I have considered. But it is not possible because of present code. (What is shown in small piece of bigger code)

Comment: Maybe consider further refactoring your code to make things simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a dictionary for mapping. Then use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

```
mapping = {'T1':20,'T2':30,'T3':40,'T4':55}

df_final = (df[['Person', 'Present_Delivery']].
              assign(Present_Delivery = df['update'].map(mapping).fillna(df['Present_Delivery']))
           )
  Person  Present_Delivery
0      A              20.0
1      B              30.0
2      C              40.0
3      D              40.0
4      E              30.0
5      F              50.0
```

Another idea using [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) along with [`pd.Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)

```
df['Present_Delivery'] = (df['Present_Delivery'].where(
                          df['update'].isna(),df['update'].map(mapping))
                          )
df_final = df.drop(columns='update')
  Person  Present_Delivery
0      A                20
1      B                30
2      C                40
3      D                40
4      E                30
5      F                50
```

Comment: This basically make the question meaningless. It was mentioned that I can use mapping if the variable name is same. You are changing the global variable name which is not allowed in larger scheme of things in the script!!!